# Android View setRotation, setRotationX(rotation), animate().setRotation work just for : 90°, 180°, 270° or 360° ;

Tags: android, mobile

View android

I want to rotate my view to *51°* and not want to work ????.

I tried `setRotation` and `setRotationX` and `setRotationY` !! but no one work.

Comment: How are you using setRotation? Because it doesn't only work with those angles.

Comment: Are you trying to rotate layout or view Component?

Comment: i want rotate RelativeLayout with subview like(ImageView and TextView)

Comment: myView.setRotation(51f); not work

Comment: Did you try to rotate just subview? And can you try to call requestLayout() after rotation Set?

Comment: setRotation work fine just for the angles : 90°, 180°, 270° or 360° !!!!

Comment: False. It works for every angle. Are you using centered pivots?

Comment: i dont use pivot just setRotation

Comment: Can you post your code and layout?

Comment: Thx friends, i fixed that by changing emulator :O :O :O